# What can be the cause for "The operation was aborted(Abort Error)" - iOS mobile web

Tags: javascript, video, mobile, mobile-safari, http-live-streaming

I have a video player for mobile web(HLS).
We asked the user to press the play button (to get the user interaction, but we are getting the following error:

`AbortError: The operation was aborted`

Any idea what can be the reason for it?
It's occur only on iOS (Chrome & Safari)

Thanks
Zee

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when playing / pausing a video element before the src had been set.